# JPA-Query for a Date in a Datetime column

Tags: date, datetime, jpa

I'm trying to build a query for all orders which were created today.

My Order-Entity has a datetime field like this:

```
@Column(name = "OrderCreationDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date orderCreationDate;
```

Named-Query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "OrderHeader.findByOrderCreationDate", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderHeader o WHERE o.orderCreationDate = :orderCreationDate")
```

I tried to build the query like this:

```
public List<OrderHeader> findFromToday() {
    Date dateToday = new Date();
    TypedQuery<OrderHeader> query = em.createNamedQuery("OrderHeader.findByOrderCreationDate", OrderHeader.class).setParameter("orderCreationDate", dateToday);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Of course the ResultList is empty since the date AND time would have to match.

Unfortunately I need the time in my database, so the orderCreationDate needs to stay datetime/timestamp.

So how can I query for a specific date, ignoring the time?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `setParameter` needs to pass in the temporal type argument also, defining what to use for comparison.

http://www.datanucleus.org/javadocs/javax.persistence/2.1/javax/persistence/Query.html#setParameter-java.lang.String-java.util.Date-javax.persistence.TemporalType-